# Best open source Server backup utility with GUI?

Tags: linux, backup, database-backup

I am looking for an open source/free server backup app with GUI (web based front end). Which app do you recommend? I search a little and came up with this list: [21 of the Best Free Linux Backup Software](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20090105114152803/Backup.html)

Which ones do you suggest. My requirement is to backup 3 servers: 1. database, 2. web server, 3. Glassfish.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be Bacula -- It is extremely flexible, works beautifully on Windows as well as unix systems, and there's lots of documentation.  Commercial support is also available.

I will however qualify that by saying that I haven't ever used a GUI for it.

Comment: what about http://sourceforge.net/projects/backuppc/ ?

Comment: I am also using bacula and i found it stable and flexible

Comment: @zengr I've never used BackupPC, but I'm suspicious of anything that claims "no client-side software" -- *especially* when you're backing up database servers.  With Bacula I can trigger a script to dump my databases prior to running the backup...